# Is it possible to specify a custom text Task Category using the EventLogAppender in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net, event-log

If you look at the Windows Event Viewer,  you'll see some tasks with Task Categories such as *Gatherer* and *Firing Agent*, but if you use log4net to log events, you can only provide a short integer value in the `category` property. I think it is the same case using `System.Diagnostics` method of logging events.

Is there some way of specifying string/text categories, or perhaps defining enums for the event viewer to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register your categories. I found this article which explains how this works (though it is a bit dated, I have the impression that the information is still correct):

http://drdobbs.com/184405714

Comment: Cheers that looks like it will work, though the program will need to run under an admin user.

Comment: Should. Not could!

Answer (score 0):

You create a DLL with both the string texts and the enums that identify them. Then you associate the DLL with your application in the registry.

There is a good tutorial here: http://www.eventlogblog.com/mt/mt-search.cgi?search=python&IncludeBlogs=1 -- I've tried it recently and it still works for current versions of the Platform SDK and Visual Studio Express. But you will have to add some folders to the PATH variable that VS sets up for you, for the executables and DLLs.